# How to use default Wordpress comments for some pages and Disqus on others?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, disqus

I've been searching for an answer for weeks without anything helpful. I have Disqus installed as my comments plugin on my Wordpress site.

I want to use Wordpress' default comments system on specific pages but continue to use disqus on my blog posts. Is there a way that this can be done?

I have a template for the pages where I want comments to appear. I've tried adding in:

```
<?php comments_template('comments.php'); ?>
```

but it still loads up Disqus. Is there a workaround on this?

I wish I didn't have to post here, but I've been searching for an answer for quite some time and have found Stackoverflow to be the best place to find these type of answers.